# Remove xsi:type after marshalling abstract class with hierarchy

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

If someone help me, that will be great. So I have a structure:

`<letters>
    <list>
        <name>Simon</name>
        <type>2</type>
        <passengerName>Johny</passengerName>
        <passengerSurname>Revelator</passengerSurname>
    </list>
    <list>
        <name>someName</name>
        <type>4</type>
        <fileURL>someUrl</fileURL>
        <specialNotes>specialNotes</specialNotes>
    </list>
</letters>`

For this structure I wrote Java Classes and they marshall and unmarshall it:
Class A
    package com.edhex.testing;

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
@XmlSeeAlso({B.class, C.class})
@XmlType
abstract public class A {
    int type;
    String name;

    @XmlElement
    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(int type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Class Letters:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Letters {
    List<A> list;

    @XmlElement
    public List<A> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<A> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

Class B:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlType
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public class B extends A {
    String fileURL;
    String specialNotes;
    @XmlElement
    public String getFileURL() {
        return fileURL;
    }

    public void setFileURL(String fileURL) {
        this.fileURL = fileURL;
    }
    @XmlElement
    public String getSpecialNotes() {
        return specialNotes;
    }

    public void setSpecialNotes(String specialNotes) {
        this.specialNotes = specialNotes;
    }
}
```

Class C:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)

public class C extends A {
    String passengerName;
    String passengerSurname;
    @XmlElement
    public String getPassengerName() {
        return passengerName;
    }

    public void setPassengerName(String passengerName) {
        this.passengerName = passengerName;
    }
    @XmlElement
    public String getPassengerSurname() {
        return passengerSurname;
    }

    public void setPassengerSurname(String passengerSurname) {
        this.passengerSurname = passengerSurname;
    }
}
```

Everything looks fine, but after marshalling which I do like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        C c = new C();
        c.setName("Simon");
        c.setType(2);
        c.setPassengerName("Johny");
        c.setPassengerSurname("Revelator");
        B b = new B();
        b.setType(4);
        b.setFileURL("someUrl");
        b.setSpecialNotes("specialNotes");
        b.setName("someName");

        List<A> list = new ArrayList<A>(2);
        list.add(c);
        list.add(b);
        Letters letter = new Letters();
        letter.setList(list);
        try {
            File file = new File("C:\file.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Letters.class);
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(letter, file);
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(letter, System.out);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I get output like this:

```
<letters>
    <list xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="c">
        <name>Lasha</name>
        <type>2</type>
        <passengerName>Johny</passengerName>
        <passengerSurname>Revelator</passengerSurname>
    </list>
    <list xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="b">
        <name>someName</name>
        <type>4</type>
        <fileURL>someUrl</fileURL>
        <specialNotes>specialNotes</specialNotes>
    </list>
</letters>
```

**Question:** How can I remove those: xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="b" in each list tag?
I know that JAXB will notify me with what type is it using, because originally mapping is using another type (A.class), but I don't need that information. Have somebody any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove xsi:type, xmlns:xs, and xmlns:xsi from JAXB Generics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192623/remove-xsitype-xmlnsxs-and-xmlnsxsi-from-jaxb-generics)

Comment: This was already discussed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192623/remove-xsitype-xmlnsxs-and-xmlnsxsi-from-jaxb-generics

Comment: @Andremoniy it is not telling how to remove those xsi:type if I think that it is unnecessary in my case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `@XmlElementRef` on the `list` property then the element for the item will be based on the `@XmlRootElement` of the referenced class and then you won't get the `xsi:type` attibute.

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Letters {
    List<A> list;

    @XmlElementRef
    public List<A> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<A> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

Comment: thats great!! haven't noticed that annotation!

Answer (score 1):

looks like you can use generics - to keep the types generic: [Remove xsi:type, xmlns:xs, and xmlns:xsi from JAXB Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192623/remove-xsitype-xmlnsxs-and-xmlnsxsi-from-jaxb-generics)

But my answer is - do not remove the xmlns:xsi declaration. I know it would look nicer to have it in the top element. But - this way it is still valid XML with valid and complete type identification. The XML is meant to be read by machines. Without the xsi:type attribute the mapping between objects and XML wouldn't be deterministic anymore (and you couldn't as well validate the XML reliably).

Have fun..
     Gabriel

Comment: yes, I agree with you... but still that xsi: type attribute annoys me(